# how does the taxation works if contract is from Spain and you are working in Germany

Tags: taxes, germany, employment, spain, payroll

I am a resident in Germany and will have a contract from Spain. My work location will still be in Germany. Which country should I pay my taxes? How can this be arranged by payroll?